# Is clean_<fieldname> supported in ModelForm?

Tags: django, modelform

In the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method) for ModelForm it is told that, to perform custom validation on the form, one must override the `.clean()` method.

However, I'd prefer to use the `clean_<fieldname>` method since I only need to validate a single field. This works for a standard `forms.Form` but there is no mention of this for what concerns `forms.ModelForm`.

Is this method supported by Django?

Comment: Yes, that's supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, certainly. See the below given example.

```
class UserForm(form.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'website', 'twitter','facebook', 'linkedin',
                  'glassdoor', 'github',)

    def clean_github(self):
        github = self.cleaned_data.get('github')
        if github and not re.match(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$', github):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please enter a valid github username')
        return github
```